# Unable to extract tar file - tar: extract not authorized

Tags: unix, solaris, tar, solaris-10

I am working on Solaris 10 machine. In that i cannot able to untar my file. Logs are given below. Anyone please suggest what may be the issue? I can able to create tar file but unable to untar. :(

```
bash-3.2# ls -lrth ConfigCheck-120614-KL.out*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 144K Jun 12 17:15 ConfigCheck-120614-KL.out
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 146K Jun 16 16:49 ConfigCheck-120614-KL.out.tar
bash-3.2# tar xvf ConfigCheck-120614-KL.out.tar 
tar: extract not authorized
bash-3.2# tar tvf ConfigCheck-120614-KL.out.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0 147377 Jun 12 17:15 2014 ConfigCheck-120614-KL.out
```

Comment: do you only get that error if the file already exists (e.g. are you not root, and hence you cannot overwrite the existing file)?

Comment: i am logged in as root and this problem happen even when the file is not existing in the same directory. for ur reference please find the log.

bash-3.2# ls -lrth

total 8461

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 14 Jun 23 13:37 SDP5_3271_10_23
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sdpuser staff 4.1M Jun 23 14:18 1_19089CXP102081_4Ux3271_10_23_EP08.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1M Jun 23 14:27 SDP5_3271_10_23.tar
bash-3.2# pwd
/opt/temp/sdp
bash-3.2# who am i
root pts/2 Jun 23 11:31 (150.236.11.66)
bash-3.2# tar xvf 1_19089CXP102081_4Ux3271_10_23_EP08.tar 
tar: extract not authorized
bash-3.2#

Comment: Looks like you might need to install gnu tar.

Answer (score 3):

Solaris 11 tar will fail with that error message if you are running as uid 0 but do not have the [Media Restore profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E36219/rights-1.html) set up in the RBAC configuration.

Unless you're trying to restore from backup, you should normally be untarring files as a normal user, not root, to avoid accidentally overwriting critical system files.